# Order emails from online shop not delivered due to SPF errors

Tags: email, spf, spamassassin

I have my domain served by two servers with different IP addresses: one for main website and another for online shop.  When a customer places an order, among other things, an email is being sent to an internal email address `sales@example.com`.  This email is sent by the server on which the online store resides. However the email is sent to be from the customer's email address, so, for example, if `customer@example.org` places an order, an email will be sent from the online store to `sales@example.com` with details of the order, pretending to be from `customer@example.org`.

On my mail server, SpamAssassin rejects these emails though because they fail SPF validation check, specifically, I get error message stating that `store.example.com is not allowed to send mail from example.org` (this is easy to understand, as my online store will not be included into `example.org` SPF record).

I am administering example.com on behalf of a client - and the client states that emails from the store need to arrive in this format (i.e. from customer@example.org as opposed to a generic store@example.com).  How can I configure SpamAssassin (via cPanel or, if necessary via back end) to accept messages delivered by store.example.com?

Comment: "this is easy to understand, as my online store will not be included into otherdomain.com SPF record" Why not?

Comment: @ceejayoz Because it's the customer's email address, which is not the right address to use.

Comment: Your client needs to give up on this "requirement". It's bad practice, and many emails will not be delivered.

Comment: So you want to whitelist mails from `mydomain.com` for the SPF or all checks?

Comment: @MichaelHampton That's easier said than done, but trying to convince your client is another thing altogether. My problem is that they used to have a VERY old email server that didn't care about SPF at all.  The services were recently migrated to newer servers with newer software, so now I have to convince the customer that what used to work for 12 years is really bad.  Basically, I have to tell my client "Yes, I know this worked for 12 years, but this is bad and has to change" or it won't work.

Comment: @sebix What I want is to disable SPF check for any delivery from my online store URL.

Comment: How about adding a Reply-To: header which contains the customer's address, and use store@mydomain.com as the From address? This way most e-mail clients will send replies to the customer's e-mail address instead of store@mydomain.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything turned out to be much simpler than I thought - SpamAssassin had nothing to do with it and the SPF rule rejection was happening on the exim level.  I modified the exim configuration to include the IP of our online store server into trusted SMTP list - and everything is now working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to solve this is to have the client's address in the `From:` header of the email, but your address in the SMTP `MAIL FROM`command.

Answer (score 0):

If the client requires emails are sent "from" their domain, then they need to add an SPF record for your services, validating this is as an approved endpoint.  The `include:` mechanism in SPF may be the way to go.

Do you host your own mail services?  If so, you likely already have an SPF record.  You could encourage your client to add a line such as `?include:store.mydomain.com` to their SPF, to allow a "neutral" validation of your domain sending as otherdomain.com.  Of course your SPF should be pretty strict, not something like `+all`.  I would recommend using the ip address of your online shop server.

---

If you are **only** worried about emails coming into your org, and not passing SPF for external recipients, you can get away with only whitelisting the `customer@otherdomain.com` addresses in SpamAssassin.  [whitelist-from SpamAssassin](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Apache+SpamAssassin#ApacheSpamAssassin-whitelist_from) link.  (I am not familiar with this configuration, YMMV.)

If you need to deliver emails to other email domains while impersonating the `customer@otherdomain.com` address, you will need to have valid SPF or you will fail checks globally.  It sounds like you're providing a service to multiple customers, so I recommend having valid SPF and instructing customers to add the `?include:` reference to their SPF records.

Comment: The From-address is a customer of the store, as far as I understood the problem.

Comment: @sebix is correct. I can't ask EVERY possible potential customer to add my online store to their SPF.

Comment: Ok then. If you are the only intended recipient, you will only need to ignore the SPF fail in SpamAssassin. If the mail sent by your store software needs to deliver to end customers, you are going to have trouble.